# Material UI select field on click of enter doesn't work as expected with Redux Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

The problem is while performing key board operations on the select field material UI.On pressing any alphabet say ;'G' to select the color green listen in the dropdown of the select field.

Expected behavior is on press of enter the selected field should appear instead none of the field is selected and validation is triggered

Attached the link of bug : https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/material-ui/

on click on enter the select field should display the selected / highlighted value
expected behaviour : http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

Comment: Have you tried adding onKeyPress to the select component? You can check if the key pressed is the enter key, and the selected option will probably also be included in the event.

Comment: @CJNaude Not working for me as well